# Passing Array in Javascript Function and escaping quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have datatable with an edit button in the last column, using mrender to pass the row values to an Edit modal.

```
{
   "targets": [7],
    "data": null,
     "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
     var editlink='<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:editbtn(\'' + data.Id + '\',\'' + data.Name + '\',' + data.regExp + ',\'' + data.validateAgainst + '\',\'' + data.Category + '\');"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
return  editlink;
}
}
```

Where data.regExp is an array containing regex expressions, if I enclose data.regExp in quotes the \  slashes are ignored.

```
   data.regExp = ["/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/",
"/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/"];
```

The editbtn function throws an error on click.
These are the values passed to the function onclick

```
 editbtn
('31','Post',/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,'email@email.com','Email');
```

How do I escape the quotes in the array and function and iterate the array values in the editbtn function and add each array value to a select dropdown option.

Comment: Better to pass whole `data` object in function like  `javascript:editbtn(data)`.

Comment: Have you tried using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for wrap your `<a>...</a>` ?